# angular google map api doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created directive for google location autocomplete input filed, I include the google api.js file in the index page, the weird thing is if I put the directive in the index.page it works, but if I put it in the other pages, it doesn't work.
directive:

```
angular.module('ecom').controller('googleMapsCtr', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.locationgoogle);
    }])
.directive('smartgooglemaps', function() {
    return {
                    restrict:'E',
                    replace:false,
                    // transclude:true,
                    controller:'googleMapsCtr',
                    template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="locationgoogle"/>',
                    link: function($scope, elm, attrs){
                        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], {});

                    }
                }
})
```

I put my directive in the accordion directive which is included by :

```
<div ng-show="modeType =='CASH_ADVANCE'" static-include="submitter/expenseentry/cash-advance.html"></div>
```

what should I do to make my directive work?

Comment: should always have an object reference in `ng-model`. Please provide better details beyond `doesn't work` which is fairly meaningless

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. doesn't work mean that the auto-complete drowdown-list will not show, the the directive just a normal input. but once I move this directive to index.page, it works fine.

Comment: you haven't shown here any example of the usage of your directive in your HTML, working or not.  When you are having issues with Angular components not loading, it is important to show the HTML that is used to declare it ***and*** any surrounding HTML, for example the location of `ng-app` and `ng-controller`.  With what you have posted here, we have no way of reproducing your issue.